# Fixing Netbeans 7.3 freezes (on startup) on OSX Mountain Lion Macbook Air

Tags: macos, java, ide

I encounter the following issues with my Netbeans 7.3 installation on my OSX Mountain Lion Macbook Air.

- When launching the app, it bounces in the Dock for about 2 minutes before it simply stops. When you click on the icon nothing happens and when you right click on it, OSX says the app is not responding.
- After Force Quitting Netbeans, I am successfully able to get the "loading" message to come up while it attempts to open. 8 times out of 10, it loads properly but other times it simply hangs while trying to load modules.

Has anyone else encountered issues like this? Are there any known fixes out there? For reference, here's what Java version I am using:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem:

Netbeans is slow because the antivirus program I have installed was scanning the application as it tried to open. If you turn off your Antivirus software, it will boot at a "normal" speed.